# Set undefined variables in a batch file FOR loop

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In a batch file an arbitrary number of variables are listed, some defined, others not. How can I set the undefined (not set to any value) variables with names starting from "_" to 1 in a FOR loop or another iterative way?

The code below only prints defined variables starting from "_" (underscore), but it doesn't set undefined variables to 1.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:Variables
set "_A=good" & set "_B=" & set "C=" & set "D=6" & set "_E=bad"
set "_F=" & set "_G=ugly"

:Core
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in ('set _') do (
    if "%%j"=="" set "%%i=1"
    echo %%i %%j)

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in ('set _') do (
    set "varn=%%i" & set "varp=%%j"
    if not %%j equ 1 (echo %%i = %%j
    ) else (set /p "%%j=Enter %%i > " 2>nul)
)
call :verify !varn! !varp!    

exit /b

:verify
rem More code
```

Comment: What do you consider as an undefined variable? type `set "_H="` and then `set _` in command prompt; what do you expect to be displayed then?

Comment: Undefined variable are those named but without value set. I don't expect them to display values untill set. The purpose of the FOR loop is to set all undefined variables to 1, i.e. make them defined. Can you suggest a different iterative method, if that one is not correct?

Comment: Type `set "_H="` and `set _`; you'll find that `_H` is not displayed; there are no "named" or defined variables in batch; as soon as you assign a non-empty value/string, a variable is defined, otherwise it is cleared and hence undefined; so your `for /F` loop only iterates through the variables you set before (`_A`, `_D`, `_E`, `_G`).

Comment: Your explanation is appreciated, but it doesn't provide a way to solve the problem of setting undefined variables to 1 in an iterative way. Hence, it doesn't answer my above question. :)

Comment: That's why it's a comment not an answer... ;-) A possible work-around could be: `for %%V in (_A _B _C _D _E _F _G) do if not defined %%V set "%%V=1"`...

Comment: Its not a workaround, since number of undefined variables may change. I don't want to edit other code sections every time when some variable names are added or removed to :Variables section. Their number doesn't matter for code execution, if each undefined var is set to 1. Also, C and D aren't included in the set.

Comment: Then I suggest that you reconsider the purpose of all this and reassess your whole script! There is no code that can distinguish between variables never defined and explicitly undefined ones (using `set "_H="`). And I don't see the point in all that, because the code using the variables will almost certainly need to state the dedicated names of the variables it wants to use anyway...

Comment: The values for undefined named variables can be supplied from an args file or in-line as batch parameters. The file or batch args only supply values, hence var names must be set in the code to assign values to proper vars, possibly via FOR loop. The var names can't be arbitrary, since they're used in other user batches.

Comment: @sambul35: I encourage you to _precisely_ define what "all undefined variables" means, because from my point of view, there are _infinite_ number of undefined variables! Do you want just the variables comprised of "underscore+ONE letter" perhaps?

Comment: I can't follow you completely, but as I said, there is a section in your code where you want to use the variables and read their values, so you have to state their names there anyway; or how else do you want to read them? To read values from a text file, use `for /F` and the related `for` variables like `%%I` (see `for /?`); to read values from command line arguments, use argument references `%1`, `%2`,... (see `call /?`).

Comment: @Aacini Sorry for not being precise enough. "Yes", code in the question refers to "underscore+ONE letter" var name, and to give an idea such ID seems sufficient. Also "yes" to your another note, undefined variable names (without attached values) can be present in :Variables section, or found in user input like batch params or args file. Processing will depend on the source. Collecting from a file is clear, while from batch args requires some agreement on input sequence. I was mostly uncertain on how to define vars present in :Variables section. :)

Comment: @aschipfl It might be couter-productive to convince a poster that his question doesn't make sense, as he might know better. :)(: For example, variables can be read like `FOR /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i  in ('set _') do (echo %%i %%j)` construct that doesn't require to state their names, unless they're undefined. In fact, that construct is present in my question, giving you such example.

Comment: You should show what you want to do with that, otherwise with the information provided it seems not quite useful... perhaps you provide also the code portion where the variables are used?

Comment: Updated the question code to satisfy your suggestion. Now what? :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I prefer a combined solution based on Aacini's answers here and elsewhere. The advantage is, it doesn't require to set extra *:AllVariables* section:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:Variables
set "vars=_A=good,_B=,_E=bad,_F=,_G=ugly"
set "C=" & set D=6

:Core
set "uars=,!vars!," & set "uars=!uars:,=" "!" & set "uars=!uars:~2,-2!"
for %%u in (!uars!) do (
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%v in (%%u) do (
        if not %%w.==. (set %%v=1) else set %%v=%%w
        echo %%v=!%%v!))

:: Restore default _vars values if needed
set "%vars:,=" & set "%"
exit /b

:: Output
_A=good
_B=1
_E=bad
_F=1
_G=ugly
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

:Variables
set "_A=good" & set "_B=" & set "C=" & set "D=6" & set "_E=bad"
set "_F=" & set "_G=ugly"

:AllVariables
rem You must define here a list with "all variables"
set "variables=_A _B C D _E _F _G"

:Core
for %%v in (%variables%) do if not defined %%v set "%%v=1"
exit /b
```

Below `:AllVariables` label you must define the variables you want, but your question did *not* defined such a method! You may collect they from parameters, or from a line in a text file, or...

Comment: What code would allow to collect undefined variables present in :Variables section into :AllVariables section? I assume such code example would give a hint, how to later add to :AllVariables section the undefined variables from other sources like batch params and args file. :) On related note, what efficient techniques allow to limit code processing to a certain code section like :Variables? Of course, GOTO or FUNCTION are known examples.

Comment: Adding vars from other sources can be done using `set "variables=!variables! %%i"` technique, but method of collecting them from :Variables section is not clear so far. Of course it can be done manually, if not possible to code.